# Negate complete regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, negation

Forcing a certain url structure "type/name" and my working regex is:

```
([a-z]+\/?[a-z]+\/?)+
```

Now I want to remove all other characters from the string via preg_replace and therefore negate the pattern above. Simple cases like [^a-z] work fine but for my pattern I don't get it working by negating the whole pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this :

```
(?!([a-z]+\/?[a-z]+\/?)+)
```

That is:

- Prefix `(?!`
- Postfix `)`

Comment: Probably this is the only direct way to negate a regexp.  So my vote is for you :)  Negating a regexp means scanning the whole string space for strings that match the first regular expresion, and if they match, just consider they unmatched.  There's no direct form to transform a regexp into its negation (or complement) One efficient algorithm is to compile the regexp to a DFA and then change all accepting states into nonaccepting states, and convert the result again back to a regexp.  But normally the regexp that results from that if far much more complex than the original one.